# How to get a return value of a count of unique values in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy, count

I have an array "station" that contains two values [28450., 29980.]. These represent station names. I want to get a count of these stations in a new variable using numpy:

```
station_count = np.unique(station)
print("The number of unique stations is ", station_count)
```

gives me:

The number of unique stations is  [28450. 29980.]

How do I get a number 2 instead of [28450. 29980.]. I have tried count but I don't seem to be getting the syntax correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently counting number of unique elements - NumPy / Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46575364/efficiently-counting-number-of-unique-elements-numpy-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `len` of the unique array:

```
station_count = len(np.unique(station))
print("The number of unique stations is ", station_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get more information by code given below:-

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,5,25,1,1])
unique, counts = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)
print(f"The number of unique values are \t {len(unique)}")
print()
for value, number in zip(unique,counts):
    print(f"The value {value} repeats \t -->> {number} times")
```

I hope you learn something new, related to your question.