# Cache variable in list comprehension

Tags: python, performance, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension, set-comprehension

Lets say I have an expensive operation `expensive(x: int) -> int` and the following list comprehension:

```
# expensive(x: int) -> int
# check(x: int) -> bool
[expensive(i) for i in range(LARGE_NUMBER) if check(expensive(i))]
```

If I want to avoid running `expensive(i)` twice for each `i`, is there any way to save it's value with  list comprehension?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57484396/vectorizing-a-pure-function-with-numpy-assuming-many-duplicates).

Comment: If the function is pure, you could wrap it with `functools.lru_cache`.

Comment: Or `[e for e in map(expensive, range(LARGE_NUMBER)) if check(e)]`.

Comment: You could use a loop, of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the walrus:

```
[cache for i in range(LARGE_NUMBER) if check(cache := expensive(i))]
```

Comment: Note this feature is only available as of Python 3.8

Answer (score 0):

You could simulate a nested comprehension:

```
 [val for i in range(LARGE_NUMBER) for val in [expensive(i)] if check(val)]
```