# Efficiently get unique elements + count - NumPy / Python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking for an extension to this question [Efficiently counting number of unique elements - NumPy / Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46575364/efficiently-counting-number-of-unique-elements-numpy-python) that can also return the count of each unique element (i.e. how many times it occurs in the array).

```
import numpy as np
max_a = 20_000
a = np.random.randint(max_a, size=10_000).astype(np.int32)

# Using np.unique
u,counts = np.unique(a,return_counts=True)

# Faster alternative suggested in the post above
q = np.zeros(max_a, dtype=int)
q[a] = 1
v = np.nonzero(q)[0]
```

I can verify that `u` and `v` are the same, and the faster method using `q` is definitely faster. However, I also want the `counts` that are returned by the `np.unique()` call. Is there a way to modify the example here to obtain those?

NB the elements of a will always be of type `np.int32` so they can be used for indexing.

Comment: Is the faster method still faster if you don't return `counts`?

Comment: Did you read all the answers in the provided link? `bincount` or Numba should do the job pretty well in your case.

Comment: Maybe try caching it with `lru_cache`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case where `a` is of type `uint`, you can use `np.bincount` which offers a fast way to get the counts. If you do have negative int's, perhaps you can add an offset to make all positive?

For example:

```py
counts = np.bincount(a) # includes 0-counts
unique = np.flatnonzero(counts)
counts = counts[unique] # remove 0-counts
```

Comment: This works! Here's a comparison of timing:
```
    def np_unique(a):
        return np.unique(a, return_counts=True)

    def fast_unique_counts(a):
        counts = np.bincount(a)
        u = np.flatnonzero(counts)
        return u, counts[u]

    def fast_unique(a, max_a):
        q = np.zeros(max_a, dtype=int)
        q[a.ravel()] = 1
        return np.nonzero(q)[0]

%timeit u1, counts1 = np_unique(a)
674 µs ± 29.4 µs per loop 
%timeit u2, counts2 = fast_unique_counts(a)
318 µs ± 123 µs per loop
%timeit u3 = fast_unique(a, max_a)
293 µs ± 6.36 µs per loop 
```